# ListBox DataSource how to update (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have an ArrayList with objects, this ArrayList is used as a DataSource to a ListBox. When new objects are added to the listbox, how can i get the listbox to update?

the code for populating the list looks lite this:

```
'Form1.ExistingArticles = The ArrayList
'Form1.LB_Articles = The Listbox

Public Sub FillArticleList()
    If Form1.ExistingArticles.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Form1.LB_Articles.DataSource = Form1.ExistingArticles
    Form1.LB_Articles.ValueMember = "ID"
    Form1.LB_Articles.DisplayMember = "ListText"
End Sub
```

When i add a new object to the Form1.ExistinArticles i can see that the new object is there, but it does not update. Calling FillArticleList() again will not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you're targeting .NET 2.0 or later then you shouldn't be using an ArrayList at all.  The List(Of T) basically superseded the ArrayList and is what you should use in most cases.
In this case, you can either use a List(Of T) and bind it to a BindingSource and bind that to the ListBox or else use a BindingList(Of T).  Both the BindingSource and BindingList(Of T) have methods that you can call when you make changes to the list to update and bound control(s).